# User permissions on upload directory

Tags: permissions, apache2, upload

Uploading files via my website fails because apache is not recognized as having write access.  However, my permissions show otherwise.  Any ideas?

When uploading via script, the script returns

```
Error:  Directory is not writable
```

Directory is `/home/username/public_html/uploads`
Directory permissions are `drwxrwsr-x`
Directory is owned by `username:webadmins`
Apache is run as `www-data` and is a member of groups `www-data webadmins`

What should I change so www-data (Apache) is able to write to this directory?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the rights of the uploads folder to 777 (read and write access for all users). But this is not secure. You should not use this on a production system or a system with multiple users.
Anyway, this would work like this
`sudo chown -R 777 /home/username/public_html/uploads`

The other (and better) way would be to use mod_ruid2 for Apache.
You can download it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-ruid/

You have to compile it and after that you have to enable the module `sudo a2enmod ruid2`

With this installed and enabled, you can edit the configuration file of the userdir module `sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`

Add the follwowing

```
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
RMode stat
RUidGid username usergroup
RGroups username usergroup
</IfModule>
```

After that, you have to restart the Apache service `sudo service apache2 restart`

With this configuration you can use the public_html directory with your user and usergroup.

But this only works, if you have only one user with an userdir public_html Apache.